# GROUP_CONCAT with DATEDIFF between outer value and a select inner value returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql-5.7

So I have a table of User and Child, the idea is to concatenate the date difference between user's join date and child's dob.

A particular user has 2 children, when I run a group_concat using this

```
SELECT u.id,GROUP_CONCAT(DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.timestamp/1000),(SELECT DATE(c2.dob) FROM Child c2 WHERE c2.user_id = u.id)) SEPARATOR ',')  AS childAge FROM User u
WHERE u.id = 1
GROUP BY u.id;
```

This gives an error that a subquery returns more than 1 row. So ok, I the run a group by c2.user_id inside the subselect but that defeats the purpose of group_concat! I just get the first child id datediff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I have answered my own question, after thinking some more over lunch this is how I solved it:

```
SELECT u.id,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.timestamp/1000),DATE(c2.dob)) SEPARATOR ',') FROM Child c2 WHERE c2.user_id = u.id)  AS childAge FROM User u

WHERE u.id = 1
GROUP BY u.id;
```

From my (limited) understanding is that this works because I am pulling out individual dob from Child table instead of grabbing them all on the 2nd half of DATEDIFF inside a sub select.

Hope this helps other people